# Refactoring Really Seems to Have Vanished from my Xcode

Tags: xcode, refactoring

I've read the similar (ok, almost identical) thread here as well as on the Apple iPhone Dev forums. I've looked carefullly at the referenced links. I have tried everything but nothing I do has brought refactoring back to life in XCode. Sigh.

I took a working, 100% Cocoa Touch project (ie, Pragmatic Programmers - Coding in Objective-C 2.0 - Movie Player) and tried to select and refactor an ivar. Nothing. Nada.

This is very odd, since about a month ago it was working. In fact, on a project that mixed C++ with Obj-C.

Should I resort to reinstalling XCode? Seems a bit like overkill, no?

Anyway, very frustrating.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Cheers,

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Rebuilding the code sense index from the project inspector window?